# Making a Batch File Faster

Tags: batch-file, passwords, brute-force

I have this little piece of code for cracking WinRAR archive passwords using a word list file.

```
title RAR Crack v_2.0
echo off
color f0
set dest=%temp%\%random%
md %dest%
cls

echo.
echo -----------------------------------------
echo ^| RAR CRACK v_2.0 - BY NOOR (#NullByte) ^|
echo -----------------------------------------
echo.
echo Drag and drop the archive to this window and press ENTER
set /p arch=
echo.
echo Drag and drop the wordlist to this window and press ENTER
set /p word=

cls
echo.
echo Starting Process . .
timeout /t 2 /nobreak>nul
color f5
cls
echo.
echo Starting Process . . .
timeout /t 1 /nobreak>nul

:start
for /F %%A in (%word%) do call :process %%A
color 0c
cls
echo.
echo -----------------------------------------
echo ^| RAR CRACK v_2.0 - BY NOOR (#NullByte) ^|
echo -----------------------------------------
echo.
echo.
echo PASSWORD NOT FOUND!
echo.
echo.
echo Author: Hussain Noor Mohamed (#NullByte)
echo E-mail: noor.xbyte@mail.com
echo.
echo Your suggestions are of great value!
pause>nul
exit

:process
cls
echo.
echo Current Password: %1
unrar e -inul -p%1 "%arch%" "%dest%"
if /i %errorlevel% equ 10 goto error
if /i %errorlevel% equ 0 goto finish %1
exit /b

:finish
color 0a
cls
echo.
echo -----------------------------------------
echo ^| RAR CRACK v_2.0 - BY NOOR (#NullByte) ^|
echo -----------------------------------------
echo.
echo.
echo PASSWORD FOUND!
echo.
echo ARCHIVE  : %arch%
echo WORDLIST : %word%
echo PASSWORD : %1
echo.
echo.
echo Author: Hussain Noor Mohamed (#NullByte)
echo E-mail: noor.xbyte@mail.com
echo.
echo Your suggestions are of great value!
pause>nul
exit

:error
color ce
cls
echo.
echo "%arch%" is not a valid rar file!
pause>nul
exit
```

The problem is that it is not that fast. (It is fast, but does not meet my expectations.) It would be really grateful if you people can suggest a way to make the program faster.

P.S Please don't copy my source code!!

Comment: get rid of the `echo` in your `:process`routine. `echo` is quite slow. But I think, your main "time-eater" is loading `unrar` (and the archive) for each iteration. But I don't see a way to avoid this (at least not with batch. If you could manage it to stay in memory instead of being loaded every time... - maybe using a ramdisk?)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Without `echo` how would the users know about the progress of the application. And can you provide me a link about using ramdisk? Thanks again!

Comment: echoing 1000 short lines needs about 4 seconds. But as I said, I don't  think, that's your major problem. As for the RAMdisk: I used to use that three decades ago. I'm not even sure, if modern windows will allow it (basically it's a driver, that takes a certain amount of the main memory and emulates a disk - small, but very fast). I would have to google about it, but you can do that yourself.

Comment: wikipedia has an article about "RAM disk". The last but one link "Benchmark" looks very promising. There are different programs and downloadlinks.

Comment: You want people to help you write your code but you don't want to help others by letting them copy it???

Comment: See http://stackexchange.com/legal - you're posting code under the Creative Commons Attribution Share Alike License.

Comment: I don't mind them copying the code if they give the source.

Answer (score 1):

As Stephan said, most of your CPU time goes into unrar running. Here are some things that I believe could help you.

1. You run unrar on all files. If your archive contains large/many files and you know they all have the same password (which is the usual case), then you can save some time by doing this: get the name of the first file in the archive (unrar lb ....) and only test that one (unrar t ... FILE). You should get the file name only once, before starting to test passwords.
2. You are running unrar sequentially, which means you do not take advantage of modern CPU features (like multi-core/threading). Most password crackers start multiple parallel processes/threads to test more passwords simultaneously, thus increasing the throughput. This is harder to do with batch files though.
3. You run unrar in extract mode, which assumes some disk activity (at minimum opening and closing a file). You could save some extra CPU ticks if you run it in test mode (unrar t), but this would be minimal.
4. Because the files don't change and you use them intensively, Windows will cache unrar and your archive (if possible) in RAM, so a RAM disk will provide little benefit to you (see also #3).

I believe 1 and 2 are the most important issues that would gain you some speed. In any case, cracking passwords is a time consuming task by itself.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But I did not full understand your second point and it would be grateful if you could explain it a little bit. By the way following the first point made the process faster!

Comment: I'm glad 1 worked. Item 2 was just an thought related to speed, but it's harder to do in batch files. Basically you can split %word% in 2 (or more) sets of words, and start parallel ":process" tasks for each of one of them. For example, if you have 2 cores and run your current script you will see about 50% load (only one core is doing the cracking). With parallel scripts you should see 100% load (because both cores are working)